# Passing -D arguments to Java command line as file

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-arguments

I want to pass -D arguments to a Java program, which will set those variables as System Properties. But I have 3 to 4 -D arguments and the list can grow dynamically, so is it possible to add all those arguments into a file and pass it as arguments ?

Default Method

```
-Dproperty=value
Set a system property value. If value is a string that contains spaces, you must enclose the string in double quotes:
            java -Dfoo="some string" SomeClass
```

I would like to do it as

```
variables.dat
-Dfoo="some String"
-Dbar="some string"
      ....
      ....

java -SOME_OPTION variables.dat SomeClass
```

Is it possible to achieve this ? Where I dint get any help from net. Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple to implement. Suppose the file is

```
-Dkey1=value1
-Dkey2=value2
```

You have to just read this file; and do in a loop do System.setProperty(key1.substring(2), value1) ; because that is ultimately what -D option do.

Comment: Yeah I thought about it. But the variables in file will have -D in prefix, since this how our windows installer will except and in case with Linux will like to invoke through command line like I specified, so finding a way to pass those values in case of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

No, the `java` executable will not read this file to parse the properties. You will have to rely on your shell to do something like echoing the properties from the file as part of the arguments to the call to the JVM.